# How to remove main index from array while having any value blank multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

How to remove main array index ,

ex.

original array

```
[4] => Array
    (
        [fullname] => chaman pura
        [email] => chamana@gmail.com
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [fullname] => sagar one
        [email] => 
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [fullname] => hello how
        [email] => how@gmail.com
    )
```

Output should be :

```
[4] => Array
        (
            [fullname] => chaman pura
            [email] => chamana@gmail.com
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [fullname] => hello how
            [email] => how@gmail.com
        )
```

tried :

```
$postArr = array_map('array_filter', $postArr);
$postArr = array_filter( $postArr );
```

and its giving

```
[5] => Array
        (
            [fullname] => sagar one
        )
```

its only removing child key, not removing parent index

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Are you trying to remove any array that has a value of blank for either fullname or email?

Comment: @nerdlyist, exactly if email found blank then want to remove main array

Comment: what about fullname or will that always have a value? Do you care if the keys change?

Comment: @nerdlyist, problably! just have to remove main index while found blank email

Comment: Do you want to preserve array keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have to use `array_filter`:

```
$arr = [ '4' => [ 'fullname' => 'chaman pura', 'email' => 'chamana@gmail.com' ],
         '5' => [ 'fullname' => 'sagar one', 'email' => '' ],
         '6' => [ 'fullname' => 'hello how', 'email' => 'how@gmail.com' ] ];


var_dump(array_filter($arr, function ($i) { return !empty($i['email']); }));
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to loop the array as far as I can ponder and check the internal arrays email.

```
$postArr = [
    ["fullname" => "chaman pura", "email" => "chamana@gmail.com"],
    ["fullname" => "sagar one", "email" => ""],
    ["fullname" => "hello how", "email" => "how@gmail.com"]
];

$postArrLen = count($postArr);
for($i=0; $i < $postArrLen; $i++){
    if(empty($postArr[$i]['email'])){
        unset($postArr[$i]);
    }
}

print_r($postArr);
```

**Additional**

I suppose this could have just been a foreach

```
foreach($postArr as $arr){
    if(empty($arr['email'])){
        unset($arr);
    }
}
```